# Use different key and secret in Laravel Amazon SDK

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-4

I'm using [aws-php-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel/tree/1.0) with laravel.

But, i have a problem.

I want to use different key and secret for different amazon sevices.

For example:
Amazon S3:

- Key: AAAAAA
- Secret: BBBBB

Amazon EC2:

- Key: DDDDD
- Secret: EEEEE

is it possible? if this is possible, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this.

```
<?php

return [
    'default' => 'local',
    'cloud' => 's3',

    'disks' => [
      's3_1' => [
          'driver' => 's3',
          'key'    => 'AAAAAA',
          'secret' => 'BBBBB',
          'region' => 'us-east-1',
          'bucket' => 'bucket1',
      ],
      's3_2' => [
          'driver' => 's3',
          'key'    => 'DDDDD',
          'secret' => 'EEEEE',
          'region' => 'us-east-1',
          'bucket' => 'bucket2',
      ],

];
```

Then refer to them

```
$s3_1 = Storage::disk('s3_1');
$s3_2 = Storage::disk('s3_2');
```

I would extract them to a .env file.

**.env**

```
S3_KEY1=AAAAAA
S3_SECRET1=BBBBB
S3_REGION1=us-east-1
S3_BUCKET1=bucket1

S3_KEY2=DDDDD
S3_SECRET2=EEEEE
S3_REGION2=us-east-1
S3_BUCKET2=bucket1
```

**config/filesystem.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'default' => 'local',
    'cloud' => 's3',

    'disks' => [
      's3_1' => [
          'driver' => 's3',
          'key'    => env('S3_KEY1'),
          'secret' => env('S3_SECRET1'),
          'region' => env('S3_REGION1'),
          'bucket' => env('S3_BUCKET1'),
      ],
      's3_2' => [
          'driver' => 's3',
          'key'    => env('S3_KEY2'),
          'secret' => env('S3_SECRET2'),
          'region' => env('S3_REGION2'),
          'bucket' => env('S3_BUCKET_MUSES2'),
      ],

];
```